update column value with cte
enter image description here
attached is my table. Can someone please help. I am looking to update column value.
For each item_id and based on agreem_id A, I wanted to update term-0,12,24,36. When Agreem_id changed to B it should update only 0,12,24.
I tried to use cte
with cte as
(select 0 n
    union all 
select n + 12 from cte where n < 36
)

select * from cte

But this doesn't change when agreem_id change
[enter image description here][2]

A table cannot be stored in a picture, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
